# How to do string separation using using keyword?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have the STRING as given below. There is no specific separator between each key. The only way is to identify the keys is using the keyword "key_1" or "key_2" etc..

All keys begin with "key_" and can never appear in the value of another:

```
STRING="key_1=mislanious_string1 key_2=miscellaneous_string2"
```

I want the output as below.

`echo $STRING1` should print:

```
key_1=mislanious_string1
```

`echo $STRING2` should print:

```
key_2=mislanious_string2
```

e.g:
If STRING="key_1=foobarzkey_2=bash" , then the output should look like , STRING1=key_1=foobarz and STRING2=key_2=bash.

There may be more keys like key_1 , key_2 , key_3 etc. Each key starts with "key_" and can never appear in the value of another:

How to this in UNIX bash shell?

Comment: How do you identify where a key starts without knowing the separator?

Comment: "key_" keyword to identify the each key.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no specific separator between each key"? Is there a space?

Comment: `STRING="key_1=foobarzkey_2=bash"`. Is that one assignment to `key_1` or separate assignments to `key_1` and `key_2`? It's the second if `z` is the separator, the first otherwise.

Comment: IF STRING="key_1=foobarzkey_2=bash" , then the output should look like , STRING1=key_1=foobarz and STRING2=key_2=bash

Comment: So all keys begin with `key_` and can never appear in the value of another?

Comment: yes , exactly - chepner

Comment: Is this really for bash or ksh?

Comment: Please update your question with all your emendations from the comments you've scattered around. You aren't giving people the full picture in your posted question, and folks shouldn't have to hunt through the comments to figure out what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @CodeGnome , I have modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `grep -P` (PCRE) to support multiple key-value pairs in input:

```
STRING="key_1=mislanious_string1key_2=miscellaneous_string2key_3=fookey_4=BASH"
grep -oP 'key_[^=]+=.*?(?=key_|$)' <<< "$STRING"
key_1=mislanious_string1
key_2=miscellaneous_string2
key_3=foo
key_4=BASH
```

To store them into BASH array you can use:

```
read -d '' -ra arr < <(grep -oP 'key_[^=]+=.*?(?=key_|$)' <<< "$STRING")
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
key_1=mislanious_string1
key_2=miscellaneous_string2
key_3=foo
key_4=BASH

declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="key_1=mislanious_string1" [1]="key_2=miscellaneous_string2" [2]="key_3=foo" [3]="key_4=BASH")'
```

**UPDATE::** Here is a **pure BASH** (non-gnu) way of splitting these strings. We first insert an invisible character before every occurrence of `key_` string and then use that for splitting the string:

```
STRING="key_1=mislanious_string1key_2=miscellaneous_string2key_3=fookey_4=BASH"
c=$'\x06'
s="${STRING//key_/${c}key_}"
arr=()
while [[ "$s" =~ ${c}(key_[^=]+=[^${c}]+)(.*) ]]; do
   arr+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
   s="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

Then to test:

```
printf "<%s>\n" "${arr[@]}"
<key_1=mislanious_string1>
<key_2=miscellaneous_string2>
<key_3=foo>
<key_4=BASH>
```

Comment: Do they all start with `key_` or can be `foo=bar` also?

Comment: +1 for the regex with a lookahead condition - note, however, that `grep -P` is a _GNU_ extension. Your array-creation statement mistakenly creates a _single_ array element, because the entire command substitution is double-quoted. You need to use `read -ra` (or `readarray` in bash 4.x) instead: `read -d '' -ra arr < <(grep -oP 'key_[^=]+=.*?(?=key_|$)' <<< "$STRING")`

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 Yes this works with gnu grep (on OSX I have it installed using `home brew`). I also corrected quoting in array creation.

Comment: Thanks. I still recommend the `read -ra` approach for array creation, because your current approach is shaky for 2 reasons: (1) it doesn't work as expected with lines with embedded whitespace (may not be a problem here - fixable), but, perhaps more importantly, (2) the input lines are subject to pathname expansion.

Comment: Thanks that's really valid point. I corrected it again. Many thanks.

Comment: @mklement0: Inspired by your answer I have now provided a pure BASH (non-GNU) solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: @anubhava: Nicely done; since you're using bash syntax, you could simplify `c=$(echo -e '\x08')` to `c=$'\x08'`.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, I totally missed that (edited now)

Answer (score 3):

I like anubhava's `grep -oP` solution best. Here's an awk solution:

```
STRING="key_15=foobarzkey_3=bash"
awk -v RS="key_" 'NR>1{split($0, a, /=/); print "STRING" a[1] "=" RS $0}' <<< "$STRING"
```

```
STRING15=key_15=foobarz
STRING3=key_3=bash
```

So, to create that output as shell variables

```
eval $(awk -v RS="key_" 'NR>1{split($0, a, /=/); print "STRING" a[1] "=" RS $0}' <<< "$STRING")
echo $STRING3    # => key_3=bash
echo $STRING15   # => key_15=foobarz
```

Comment: +1 for the elegant `awk` command (requires _GNU_ `awk` or `mawk`). The `eval` is convenient, but can easily go awry (just append `;ls` to the input string, for instance). The `while read -r def ... declare "$def" ...` (or `typeset`) approach from my answer is safer.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>This answer originally didn't recognize keys not preceded by whitespace. This has been fixed. In its current form this answer provides value as a *portable* solution. If you disagree, please let me know.</sup>

The answers provided by [Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958061/45375) and [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24957654/45375) are helpful, but use ***GNU* extensions not available on all platforms** (`grep -P`, `awk` with a multi-char. `RS` value).

Here's a **POSIX-compliant** **`sed` solution** that should work on most platforms, using either `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh` as the shell:

```
str='key_1=mislanious_string1 key_2=miscellaneous_string2key_3=last'

while read -r varDef; do 
  [[ -n $varDef ]] && typeset "$varDef"
done < <(sed 's/\(key_\([0-9]\{1,\}\)=\)/\'$'\n''string\2=\1/g' <<<"$str")

#'# Print the variables created ($string1, $string2, $string3).
typeset -p ${!string@}
```

Note that *lowercase* variable names (`string1`, ...) are used so as to prevent potential conflicts with environment variables.

- `sed` is used to split the string into key-value tokens each on their own line, preceded by the desired target variable name and `=`, effectively outputting *shell variable assignments*; e.g., for `key_1`, the sed command passes out:
  `string1=key_1=mislanious_string1`
- The `while` loop then reads each output line and uses `typeset` to declare and assign the variable (note that `typeset` was chosen for `ksh` compatibility - while `typeset` also works in `bash` and `zsh` you'd typically use `declare` there); `[[ -n $varDef ]]` ignores the empty line that the `sed` output starts with.
- Note: This solution trims *trailing* whitespace from values, consistent with the example in the question. This trimming happens due to use of `read` with the default `$IFS` value (internal field separators) - to preserve trailing whitespace, simply use `IFS= read` instead of just `read`.
- Also note that use of process substitution to provide input (`while ... <(sed ...)`) (as opposed to a pipeline (`sed ... | while ...`) is required to ensure that the variables are defined in the *current shell* (rather than in a *subshell*, which would result in variables not visible to the current shell).

---

Some background info on what makes the above `sed` command POSIX-compliant:

- POSIX only mandates *basic* regular expressions for `sed`, which takes away many features (e.g., quantifiers `?` and `+`, alternation (`|`)) and makes escaping more cumbersome (e.g., `(` and `)` must be `\`-escaped).
- POSIX `sed` also doesn't support escape sequences such as `\n` in *replacement* strings passed to `s`, so [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) is used to splice an `\`-escaped *actual* newline into the replacement string using `$'\n'`.

As an example of how useful the non-POSIX *GNU* `sed` extensions are, here's an equivalent command taking full advantage of GNU sed's features (*extended* regular expressions, support for `\n`), resulting in a shorter and more readable command:

```
sed -r 's/(key_([0-9]+)=)/\nstring\2=\1/g' <<<"$str"
```

Comment: a complicating factor is that the key pairs **might not** have any whitespace in between: `key_1=onekey_2=two`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for catching that - fixed now. The fix actually allowed a straightforward POSIX solution (the only thing to note is that trailing whitespace is removed from the values, but I assume that's OK).

Comment: Just noticed an unnecessary downvote on this useful answer when gnu grep/awk are not available +1.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest solution can be overlooked:

```sh
STRING="key_1=mislanious_string1key_2=miscellaneous_string2"

read STRING1 STRING2<<<${STRING//key_/ key_}

echo $STRING1
echo $STRING2
```